# How to run laravel migration and DB seeder except one

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations, laravel-seeding

I am having many migration and seeder files to run, Although I will need to run all files but currently I need to skip one migration and seeder.

How could I skip one file from laravel migration and db seeder command.

I do not want to delete files from the migrations or seeds folder to skip the file.

Comment: Yes sir, all answers are helpfull @KamilKiełczewski

Comment: Yes, I can upvote, but I am sorry to say `300+` people have seen your answer and they don't realize to upvote. I am not good in talking/writting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Laravel doesn't give you a default method to do it. However, you can create your own console commands and seeder to achieve it.
Let's say you have this default `DatabaseSeeder` class:

```
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(ExampleTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(UserSamplesTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

the goal is to create a new command overriding "db:seed" and pass a new parameter, an "except" parameter, to the `DatabaseSeeder` class.

This is the final code, I created on my Laravel 5.2 instance and tried:

Command, put in app/Console/Commands, don't forget to update your Kernel.php:

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
class SeedExcept extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'db:seed-except {--except=class name to jump}';
    protected $description = 'Seed all except one';
    public function handle()
    {
        $except = $this->option('except');
        $seeder = new \DatabaseSeeder($except);
        $seeder->run();
    }
}
```

DatabaseSeeder

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    protected $except;

    public function __construct($except = null) {
        $this->except = $except;
    }

    public function call($class)
    {
        if ($class != $this->except)
        {
            echo "calling $class \n";
            //parent::call($class);  // uncomment this to execute after tests
        }
    }

    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(ExampleTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(UserSamplesTableSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

It the code, you'll find that I commented the line that calls the seed and added an echo for testing purposes.

Executing this command:

> php artisan db:seed-except

will give you:

> calling ExampleTableSeeder
>   calling UserSamplesTableSeeder

However, adding "except":

> php artisan db:seed-except --except=ExampleTableSeeder

will give you

> calling UserSamplesTableSeeder

This works overriding the default `call` method of your `DatabaseSeeder` class and calling the parent only if the name of the class is not in the $except variable. The variable is populated by the `SeedExcept` custom command.

Regarding migrations, the thing is similar but a little bit more difficult.

I can't give you tested code for this by now, but the thing is:

- you create a `migrate-except` command that overrides the `MigrateCommand` class (namespace Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations, located in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Console/Migrations/MigrateCommand.php).
- the `MigrateCommand` takes a `Migrator` object (namespace Illuminate\Database\Migrations, path vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php) in the constructor (injected via IoC). The `Migrator` class owns the logic that reads all the migrations inside the folder and execute it. This logic is inside the `run()` method
- create a subclass of `Migrator`, for example `MyMigrator`, and override the `run()` method to skip the files passed with the special option
- override the `__construct()` method of your `MigrateExceptCommand` and pass your `MyMigrator`: `public function __construct(MyMigrator $migrator)`

If I have time I'll add the code for an example before the bounty ends

**EDIT**
as promised, here's an example for migrations:

MyMigrator class, extends Migrator and contains the logic to skip files:

```
namespace App\Helpers;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator;
class MyMigrator extends Migrator
{
    public $except = null;

    // run() method copied from it's superclass adding the skip logic
    public function run($path, array $options = [])
    {
        $this->notes = [];

        $files = $this->getMigrationFiles($path);

        // skip logic
        // remove file from array
        if (isset($this->except))
        {
            $index = array_search($this->except,$files);
            if($index !== FALSE){
                unset($files[$index]);
            }
        }
        var_dump($files); // debug

        $ran = $this->repository->getRan();
        $migrations = array_diff($files, $ran);
        $this->requireFiles($path, $migrations);

        //$this->runMigrationList($migrations, $options);  // commented for debugging purposes
    }
}
```

The MigrateExcept custom command

```
namespace App\Console\Commands;
use Illuminate\Console\Command;
use Illuminate\Database\Console\Migrations\MigrateCommand;
use App\Helpers\MyMigrator;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migrator;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;

class MigrateExcept extends MigrateCommand
{
    protected $name = 'migrate-except'; 

    public function __construct(MyMigrator $migrator)
    {   
        parent::__construct($migrator);
    }

    public function fire()
    {
        // set the "except" param, containing the name of the file to skip, on our custom migrator
        $this->migrator->except = $this->option('except');
        parent::fire();
    }

    // add the 'except' option to the command
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return [
            ['database', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The database connection to use.'],

            ['force', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Force the operation to run when in production.'],

            ['path', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'The path of migrations files to be executed.'],

            ['pretend', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Dump the SQL queries that would be run.'],

            ['seed', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Indicates if the seed task should be re-run.'],

            ['step', null, InputOption::VALUE_NONE, 'Force the migrations to be run so they can be rolled back individually.'],

            ['except', null, InputOption::VALUE_OPTIONAL, 'Files to jump'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Last, you need to add this to a service provider to permit the Laravel IoC resolve the dependencies

```
namespace App\Providers;
use App\Helpers\MyMigrator;
use App\Console\Commands\MigrateExcept;


class CustomServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot($events);

        $this->app->bind('Illuminate\Database\Migrations\MigrationRepositoryInterface', 'migration.repository');
        $this->app->bind('Illuminate\Database\ConnectionResolverInterface', 'Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager');

        $this->app->singleton('MyMigrator', function ($app) {
            $repository = $app['migration.repository'];
            return new MyMigrator($repository, $app['db'], $app['files']);
        });
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add `Commands\MigrateExcept::class` in the Kernel.php

Now, if you execute

> php artisan migrate-except

you have:

```
array(70) {
  [0] =>
  string(43) "2014_04_24_110151_create_oauth_scopes_table"
  [1] =>
  string(43) "2014_04_24_110304_create_oauth_grants_table"
  [2] =>
  string(49) "2014_04_24_110403_create_oauth_grant_scopes_table"
  ...
```

but adding the except param:

> php artisan migrate-except --except=2014_04_24_110151_create_oauth_scopes_table

```
array(69) {
  [1] =>
  string(43) "2014_04_24_110304_create_oauth_grants_table"
  [2] =>
  string(49) "2014_04_24_110403_create_oauth_grant_scopes_table"
```

So, recap:

- we create a custom migrate-except command, `MigrateExcept` class, extending MigrateCommand
- we create a custom migrator class, `MyMigrator`, extending the behavior of the standard `Migrator`
- when MigrateExcept is fire(), pass the name of the file to skip to our `MyMigrator` class
- `MyMigrator` overrides the `run()` method of `Migrator` and skip the passed migration
- More: since we need to instruct Laravel IoC about the new created classes, so it can inject them correctly, we create a Service Provider

The code is tested so it should work correctly on Laravel 5.2 (hoping that cut&paste worked correctly :-) ...if anyone has any doubt leave a comment

Comment: Regarding `If I have time I'll add the code for an example` Please provide whenever you get free time for this.

Comment: I'll do between today and tomorrow

Comment: Thanks for all your support

Comment: I added the example for the migration, more complicated that the seed but works. Let me know if it fits your needs.

Answer (score 4):

Skipping seeds are very simple, migrations not so much. To skip a seed, remove the following from your DatabaseSeeder class.

```
$this->call(TableYouDontWantToSeed::class);
```

For migrations, There are three ways you can do it:

- Put the class you don't want to migrate into a different folder.
- Insert your migrations into the database manually (Bindesh Pandya's answer elaborated).
- Rename the file that you don't want to migrate to something like `UsersTableMigration.dud`.

Hope this helps

Comment: downvote because the OP specifically said that he don't want to remove migrations manually from the seeder class

Comment: No you just downvoted so we would have the same amount of votes...thanks a lot.

Comment: If it was the case, why would I have commented and letting know the source of the downvote? Since now it seems that you downvoted my question for revenge (what's your age?) please explain the reason behind it. Regards

Comment: he said specifically that he doesn't want the solution that you are proposing. So difficult to understand?

Comment: He never said he didn't want to delete migration calls from the databasemigration file he just said he didn't want files deleted.

Comment: Removing a file or removing a function call manually is the same. There is the need to update a source file that probably is versioned, and so each time you pull/push from repo you have to apply the update again. However, I don't have more time to waste explaining you this, keep doing things wrong and give bad advices and enjoy. Regards

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem in my project but after long time wasting in R & D i have found that Laravel does not provide any way to do this with migration and seeding but you have 2 ways to do this.

1) you'll save a lot of time just putting them into different folders.
   You could theoretically **make your own artisan command** that does what 
   you want, or **spoofs its by making directories, moving files, and running 
   php artisan migrate.**

For the seeders, just make a seeder and call the others seeders you want to run from with in it. Then just be explicit about what seeder you want to run. Try php artisan `db:seed --help` for more details there.

2) you can create a table Manually (which has same name as migration table is creating in you db) and insert the values of migration like this

```
insert into migrations(migration, batch) values('2015_12_08_134409_create_tables_script',1);
```

so migrate command will not create table which is already exist in migration table.

Answer (score 1):

If you want just omit (but keep) migration and seeder:

1. Rename your migration by removing `.php` extension: `mv your_migration_file.php your_migration_file`
2. Go to: `DatabaseSeeder.php` and comment out line with your unwanted seeder: `//$this->call('YourSeeder');`.
3. Run: `php artisan migrate --seed`
4. Execute below sql query on db (be careful, there should be migration file name WITHOUT extension) (this will prevent artisan migrate to execute your_migration_file in future):

   INSERT INTO `migrations` (`migration`, `batch`) VALUES (`your_migration_file`, 1)
5. Rename back your migration file: `mv your_migration_file your_migration_file.php`
6. Uncomment your seeder in `DatabaseSeeder.php`

And you are done. Now when you run `php artisan migrate` any migration should be executed (except new one if you add some new migration files).

Answer (score 0):

just an idea comment **seeder** and **schema**. this is the way i guess

```
//$this->call(HvAccountsSeeder::class);

//Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
          //  $table->increments('id');
          //  $table->string('name');
          //  $table->string('email')->unique();
          //  $table->string('password');
          //  $table->rememberToken();
           // $table->timestamps();
       // });
// Schema::drop('users');
```

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer your question, Laravel does not have a way to do this currently.

If I understand you correctly, I assume you're looking for a way to temporarily disable/skip a specific class from the default DatabaseSeeder.

You can easily [create your own command](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#writing-commands) which will accept a string such as a model/table name and attempt to run the migration and seed for that particular table. You will simply need something like the following:

```
public function handle(){ //fire for Laravel 4.*

    $tables = explode(',', $this->option('tables'));//default []
    $skip = explode(',', $this->option('skip'));//default [] 
    $migrations = glob("*table*.php");//get all migrations
    foreach($migrations as $migrate){
        //if tables argument is set, check to see if part of tables
        //if file name not like any in skip.. you get the point
```